# How should i handle WebException Unable to connect to the remote server?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that the website have ap roblem now it was excpected but how should i handle this case now and in the future ?

```
page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
```

page is string variable.

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
       at ScrollLabelTest.Form1..ctor() in e:\scrolllabel\ScrollLabel\ScrollLabel\Form1.cs:line 41
       at ScrollLabelTest.Program.Main() in e:\scrolllabel\ScrollLabel\ScrollLabel\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.203.52.152:80
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10060
       NativeErrorCode=10060
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
            at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the request in a try-catch-condition and, depending on how important page is, stop the program with an error message or contiunue with an empty string and just plan our program accordingly

Comment: Rooxo should i put the try and catch and try the web page in a timer lets say every 60 seconds or every few minutes ? I mean once try and catch in the constructor and if its throwing the exception then move it to a timer and then turn the timer on and try and catch it there untill the web page will work. Is that a good logic ? If so how to do it ?

Comment: I would not try to reach the website all the time. If it's really necessary to have to content just exit with an error and let the user decide when to try again